# Statically initialize variable from super class in each subclass

Tags: java, static

I'd like to create an abstract super class, called Unit and give it a number of protected static fields, such as name, health, attackPower etc.

```
public abstract class Unit {
    protected static String name;
    protected static int maxHealth;
    protected static int atkPower;

    public String getName() {
        return name; 
    }
}
```

I'd then like to create several subclasses, such as Soldier, Wizard and Tank, and statically allocate the protected field in each of the classes, so that all Soldiers have the same field values, all Wizards have the same field values, and all Tanks have the same field values. I tried something like this:

```
public class Soldier extends Unit {
    static {
        name = "Soldier";
        maxHealth = 80;
        atkPower = 15;
    }
}

public class Wizard extends Unit {
    static {
        name = "Wizard";
        maxHealth = 60;
        atkPower = 25;
    }
}
```

If I create a Wizard object, wizard, and then call wizard.getName() I get "Wizard". However if I then create a Soldier object, soldier, calling wizard.getName() returns "Soldier" instead. The soldier object statically overwrote the values of the variables in the wizard and soldier classes.

```
Wizard wizard = new Wizard();
wizard.getName(); //Wizard
Soldier soldier = new Soldier();
wizard.getName(); //Soldier
```

Is there any way to do what I want to do, that is keep different static values for the same variable in each subclass?

Comment: "Don't use `static`" is correct.  In the context of the problem you've stated, `static` is a terrible idea.  Use [instance variables.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: @shadowarcher Is there any reason you want to keep the variables as static?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is IMHO to make `getName()` (same for health etc) [`abstract`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

```
public abstract class Unit {    
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

and

```
public class Wizard extends Unit {

    private static final String NAME = "Wizard";

    @Override
    public String getName() { 
        return NAME; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the members static. Make abstract methods that subclasses have to override for each of these fields. This way you also restrict access to fields that shouldn't be `set` again, and are only accessed in a `get` context:

```
public abstract class Unit {
    public void battleCry() {
        System.out.println("RAWR! I am a " + name() + 
            "! Tremble at my " + atkPower() + 
            " attack points!");
    }

    public abstract String name();
    public abstract int maxHealth();
    public abstract int atkPower();
}
```

And then subclasses override these:

```
public class Wizard extends Unit {
    protected final String name = "Wizard";

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int maxHealth() {
        return 60;
    }

    @Override
    public int atkPower() {
        return 25;
    }
}
```

This makes it easier for further subclasses to override these methods as well:

```
public class BossWizard extends Wizard {
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "Boss" + super.name();
    }

    @Override
    public int maxHealth() {
        return super.maxHealth() * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int atkPower() {
        return super.atkPower() * 2;
    }

    public void specialAtk() {
        // Something special for the BossWizard
    }
}
```

You can see now if you have an instance of `Wizard` and `BossWizard` respectively, the battlecry is different:

```
wizardInstance.battleCry();     // RAWR! I am a Wizard! Tremble at my 60 attack points!
bosswizardInstance.battleCry(); // RAWR! I am a BossWizard! Tremble at my 120 attack points!
```